# $\pi$ out of a right triangle and a circle

Tags: proof-writing, circles, triangles, area, pi

I've a right triangle that is inscribed in a circle with radius $r$ the hypotunese of the triangle is equal to the diameter of the circle and the two other sides of the triangle are equal to eachother.

> Prove that when you divide the area of the circle by the area of the triangle that you will get $\pi$.

This is what I did:

The area of a triangle is $\frac{height\times width}{2}$ and the area of a circle is $\pi r^2$. Now I do not know how to continue.

Comment: Have you drawn a picture?  Have you determined any special properties about this triangle.  Any ideas how to calculate height and width?

Comment: @DougM No the problem is given without a picture.

Comment: I didn't ask if the problem was given with a picture.  I asked if you have tried to draw a picture.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, first of all let's summarise the things we can say about this problem and after that we can set up a system of equations.

> 1. By the [Pythagorean theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pythagorean_theorem), we can write:
>      $$\left|\text{AB}\right|^2=\left|\text{AC}\right|^2+\left|\text{BC}\right|^2\tag1$$
>       2. The [area enclosed](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Circle#Area_enclosed) by a [circle](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Circle) is given by:
>      $$\mathcal{A}_{\space\circ}=\pi\cdot\text{r}_{\space\circ}^2\tag2$$
>
> Where $\text{r}_{\space\circ}$ is the radius of the circle.
>
> 3. The connection between the [radius](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Radius) and the diameter of a circle is given by:
>      $$\text{d}_{\space\circ}=2\cdot\text{r}_{\space\circ}\tag3$$
>       4. The area of a [triangle](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Triangle#Computing_the_area_of_a_triangle%5C) is given by:
>      $$\mathcal{A}_{\space\triangle}=\frac{1}{2}\cdot\text{b}_{\space\triangle}\cdot\text{h}_{\space\triangle}\tag4$$
>      Where $\text{b}_{\space\triangle}$ is the length of the base of the triangle, and $\text{h}_{\space\triangle}$ is the height or altitude of the triangle.

---

Now, from your question we know that:

- The [Hypotenuse](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hypotenuse) of the triangle is equal to the diameter of the circle:
$$\left|\text{AB}\right|=\text{d}_{\space\circ}\tag5$$
 - The two other sides of the [right triangle](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Triangle#Right_triangles), $\triangle\text{ABC}$, are equal to each other:
$$\left|\text{AC}\right|=\left|\text{BC}\right|\tag6$$
 - The $\text{b}_{\space\triangle}$ and $\text{h}_{\space\triangle}$ of $\triangle\text{ABC}$ are equal to each other and equal to the two other sides of the right triangle:
$$\text{b}_{\space\triangle}=\text{h}_{\space\triangle}=\left|\text{AC}\right|=\left|\text{BC}\right|\tag7$$

So, we can write:

$$
\begin{cases}
\left|\text{AB}\right|=\text{d}_{\space\circ}\\
\\
\text{d}_{\space\circ}=2\cdot\text{r}_{\space\circ}\\
\\
\mathcal{A}_{\space\circ}=\pi\cdot\text{r}_{\space\circ}^2\\
\\
\left|\text{AB}\right|^2=\left|\text{AC}\right|^2+\left|\text{AC}\right|^2=2\cdot\left|\text{AC}\right|^2\\
\\
\mathcal{A}_{\space\triangle}=\frac{1}{2}\cdot\text{b}_{\space\triangle}\cdot\text{h}_{\space\triangle}\\
\\
\text{b}_{\space\triangle}=\text{h}_{\space\triangle}=\left|\text{AC}\right|=\left|\text{BC}\right|
\end{cases}\tag8
$$

Which give for $\mathcal{A}_{\space\triangle}$:

$$\mathcal{A}_{\space\triangle}=\frac{\mathcal{A}_{\space\circ}}{\pi}\space\Longleftrightarrow\space\frac{\mathcal{A}_{\space\circ}}{\mathcal{A}_{\space\triangle}}=\pi\tag9$$

Answer (score 2):

Hints:

- You need to calculate the height and width in terms of $r$: there are two ways of doing this which will give the same area
- You need to divide the area of the circle by the area of the triangle

[image: ![enter image description here]

Answer (score 1):

Hint: Find the side of the triangle using pythagoras theorem.
$hypotenuse=2r$

Answer (score 1):

The task given "the right triangle" and "two other sides of the triangle are equal to each other". This means this is a right iscoceles triangle or $45-45-90$ triangle.

Assume that this is the $45-45-90$ triangle $ABC$ right and isoceles at $A$, draw the altitude $AH$ (perpendicular to $BC$), then we can prove that $HA=HB=HC=\dfrac{BC}{2}=r$. So the area of $\Delta{ABC}$ is:

$\dfrac{\text{base}\times \text{height}}{2}=\dfrac{2r\times r}{2}=r^2$

Alternatively, you can also use the Pythagorean theorem to calculate $AB$ and $AC$, then use the special formula to calculate the area of the right triangle (in this case, it is also isoceles).

Answer (score 1):

Hint: The area of this triangle is given by $$A_1=\frac{2r\cdot r}{2}=r^2$$ and the area of the circle is $$A_2=\pi r^2$$

Comment: The OP seems aware of these formulas already.

Answer (score 1):

Consider the triangle $\triangle ABC$ with angles $45^\circ-90^\circ -45^\circ$
and hypotenuse $BC = 2r$

$AB = BC\cdot \cos(45^\circ) = \sqrt2r$

$AC = BC\cdot \sin(45^\circ) = \sqrt2r$

Area of triangle  = $\frac12\cdot AB\cdot AC = r^2$

ratio = $\frac{\pi r^2}{r^2} = \pi$